# How to load default profile image if user's original profile image not found

Tags: javascript

I stuck at one situation that, want to load `default profile image` to display for the user who didn't upload `his/her profile image`. I don't know how to achieve that. Below is the code I've written so far

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var rowsArray = []
    var i, j;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table = "";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("messageset");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var name = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var row = "<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"msgtime b1\"><?php $messagetime = $message->time ;if($messagetime!= 'yo'){echo convert(time() - $messagetime);}?></div><div class=\"b1\" ><img class='imgs' src=\"" + "../users/"
            + name + "/notification/profilepic.svg" + "\" width=\"30px\" height=\"30x\" alt=\"avatar\" style=\"border-radius: 45px;\" class=\"image\" ></div><div class=\"b2 msginname\" >" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</div> <div class=\"cmoti \"><a href=\"online.php\">check motive</a></div><div class=\"msgoriginal\">" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</div></div>";
        rowsArray.push(row)
    }
    table += rowsArray.reverse().join('');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = name;
}
```

Consider my image file paths will be like below from the server response

```
" ../users/user1/notification/profilepic.svg "

" ../users/user2/notification/profilepic.svg " - This image doesn't exist, as user didn't upload his/her picture

" ../users/user2/notification/profilepic.svg " and so on...
```

If you see second string in image file paths, second image doesn't exist, so I want to display another default profile image

My dynamic image html is give below from the above code I posted

```
<img class='imgs' src=\"" + "../users/" + name + "/notification/profilepic.svg" + "\" width=\"30px\" height=\"30x\" alt=\"avatar\" style=\"border-radius: 45px;\" class=\"image\" >
```

How can I load default profile image if original one not found?

Comment: Are you asking for, how to do in node.js?

Comment: i dont know but it is directory of my website i dont know node expect name can you help me

Comment: Node.js is a run time environment, which allows us to write and execute javascript at server side. And using javascript we can't access folders or files in the client system. But using Node.js we can access files in the server. That's what I am asking, you are doing programming at client side or server side?

Comment: now its totally client side thanks

Comment: Okay then, can you explain what do you want to do in both if and else blocks? I mean if file exists `do something` else `do something`. I want that `do something` to know what you are trying to do...

Comment: i have a statement assume , `var k = abc ; ` and it is like `<img src=/"../img" + if( fileexist == true ){ k;}else{ "different directory";}  + "pic.jpg/" alt="pic">` hopw you understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177892/discussion-between-javascript-lover-skt-and-anjali).

Comment: Anjali, I've updated your question, approve that edit